# C++ computer vision perspective rendering

Tags: c++, computer-vision

I have a file of vertex coordinates. I am having a problem displaying the image resulting from joining each of the coordinates with line segments. Ive been getting countless errors. Any help or ideas to solve the problem?

```
bool computePixelCoordinates(
const Vec3f &pWorld,
const Matrix44f &cameraToWorld,
const float &canvasWidth,
const float &canvasHeight,
const int &imageWidth,
const int &imageHeight,
Vec2i &pRaster)
{
// First transform the 3D point from world space to camera space. 
// It is of course inefficient to compute the inverse of the cameraToWorld
// matrix in this function. It should be done outside the function, only once
// and the worldToCamera should be passed to the function instead. 
// We are only compute the inverse of this matrix in this function ...
Vec3f pCamera;
Matrix44f worldToCamera = cameraToWorld.inverse();
worldToCamera.multVecMatrix(pWorld, pCamera);
// Coordinates of the point on the canvas. Use perspective projection.
Vec2f pScreen;
pScreen.x = pCamera.x / -pCamera.z;
pScreen.y = pCamera.y / -pCamera.z;
// If the x- or y-coordinate absolute value is greater than the canvas width 
// or height respectively, the point is not visible
if (std::abs(pScreen.x) > canvasWidth || std::abs(pScreen.y) > canvasHeight)
return false;
// Normalize. Coordinates will be in the range [0,1]
Vec2f pNDC;
pNDC.x = (pScreen.x + canvasWidth / 2) / canvasWidth;
pNDC.y = (pScreen.y + canvasHeight / 2) / canvasHeight;
// Finally convert to pixel coordinates. Don't forget to invert the y coordinate
pRaster.x = std::floor(pNDC.x * imageWidth);
pRaster.y = std::floor((1 - pNDC.y) * imageHeight);

return true;
}

int main(...)
{
...
Matrix44f cameraToWorld(...);
Vec3f pWorld(...);
float canvasWidth = 2, canvasHeight = 2;
uint32_t imageWidth = 512, imageHeight = 512;
// The 2D pixel coordinates of pWorld in the image if the point is visible
Vec2i pRaster;
if (computePixelCoordinates(pWorld, cameraToWorld, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight, pRaster)) {
std::cerr << "Pixel coordinates " << pRaster << std::endl;
}
else {
std::cert << Pworld << " is not visible" << std::endl;
}
...

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *Ive been getting countless errors*?

Comment: practice.cpp:2:7: error: ‘Vec3f’ does not name a type
 const Vec3f &pWorld,
       ^
practice.cpp:3:7: error: ‘Matrix44f’ does not name a type
 const Matrix44f &cameraToWorld,
       ^
practice.cpp:8:1: error: ‘Vec2i’ has not been declared
 Vec2i &pRaster)
 ^
practice.cpp: In function ‘bool computePixelCoordinates(const int&, const int&, const float&, const float&, const int&, const int&, int&)’:
practice.cpp:15:1: error: ‘Vec3f’ was not declared in this scope
 Vec3f pCamera;

Comment: worldToCamera.multVecMatrix(pWorld, pCamera);
 ^
practice.cpp:17:37: error: ‘pCamera’ was not declared in this scope
 worldToCamera.multVecMatrix(pWorld, pCamera);

Comment: practice.cpp:19:1: error: ‘Vec2f’ was not declared in this scope
 Vec2f pScreen;
 ^
practice.cpp:20:1: error: ‘pScreen’ was not declared in this scope
 pScreen.x = pCamera.x / -pCamera.z;
 ^
practice.cpp:24:5: error: ‘abs’ is not a member of ‘std’
 if (std::abs(pScreen.x) > canvasWidth || std::abs(pScreen.y) > canvasHeight)

Comment: practice.cpp:24:42: error: ‘abs’ is not a member of ‘std’
 if (std::abs(pScreen.x) > canvasWidth || std::abs(pScreen.y) > canvasHeight)
                                          ^
practice.cpp:27:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘pNDC’
 Vec2f pNDC;
       ^
practice.cpp:28:1: error: ‘pNDC’ was not declared in this scope
 pNDC.x = (pScreen.x + canvasWidth / 2) / canvasWidth;
 ^
practice.cpp:31:9: error: request for member ‘x’ in ‘pRaster’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
 pRaster.x = std::floor(pNDC.x * imageWidth);

Comment: practice.cpp:31:13: error: ‘floor’ is not a member of ‘std’
 pRaster.x = std::floor(pNDC.x * imageWidth);
             ^
practice.cpp:32:9: error: request for member ‘y’ in ‘pRaster’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
 pRaster.y = std::floor((1 - pNDC.y) * imageHeight);
         ^
practice.cpp:32:13: error: ‘floor’ is not a member of ‘std’
 pRaster.y = std::floor((1 - pNDC.y) * imageHeight);
             ^
practice.cpp: In function ‘int main(...)’:
practice.cpp:39:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token

Comment: practice.cpp:41:1: error: ‘Vec3f’ was not declared in this scope
 Vec3f pWorld(...);
 ^
practice.cpp:43:1: error: ‘uint32_t’ was not declared in this scope
 uint32_t imageWidth = 512, imageHeight = 512;
 ^
practice.cpp:45:1: error: ‘Vec2i’ was not declared in this scope
 Vec2i pRaster;
 ^
practice.cpp:46:29: error: ‘pWorld’ was not declared in this scope
 if (computePixelCoordinates(pWorld, cameraToWorld, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight, pRaster)) {

Comment: practice.cpp:46:37: error: ‘cameraToWorld’ was not declared in this scope
 if (computePixelCoordinates(pWorld, cameraToWorld, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight, pRaster)) {
                                     ^
practice.cpp:46:79: error: ‘imageWidth’ was not declared in this scope
 if (computePixelCoordinates(pWorld, cameraToWorld, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight, pRaster)) {

Comment: There is an edit button at the bottom of the post.  Please edit the question to contain the errors.

Comment: practice.cpp:46:91: error: ‘imageHeight’ was not declared in this scope
 if (computePixelCoordinates(pWorld, cameraToWorld, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight, pRaster)) {

Comment: practice.cpp:46:104: error: ‘pRaster’ was not declared in this scope
 if (computePixelCoordinates(pWorld, cameraToWorld, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight, pRaster)) {
                                                                                                        ^
practice.cpp:47:1: error: ‘cerr’ is not a member of ‘std’
 std::cerr << "Pixel coordinates " << pRaster << std::endl;
 ^
practice.cpp:47:49: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
 std::cerr << "Pixel coordinates " << pRaster << std::endl;

Comment: practice.cpp:50:1: error: ‘cert’ is not a member of ‘std’
 std::cert << Pworld << " is not visible" << std::endl;
 ^
practice.cpp:50:14: error: ‘Pworld’ was not declared in this scope
 std::cert << Pworld << " is not visible" << std::endl;
              ^
practice.cpp:50:45: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
 std::cert << Pworld << " is not visible" << std::endl;
                                             ^
practice.cpp:52:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token

Comment: These are the errors I'm getting. Any suggestions on how to display an image joined by lines from a file of vertex coordinates?

Comment: Wow. You know, it would be a lot better if you edit those errors into the original question where you can format them rather than posting them as multiple comments where you can't.

Answer (score 0):

This code is using a library for matrix operations, which defines types like `Matrix44f` and `Vec3f`. You need to get this library, include the appropriate headers, and link against it.